# Can not input the data to Array list including both string and values

Tags: java, arraylist

Please help me guys, I am struggling with this exercise for a long time
In this code I want user to input the data, and then add these data to the Course before adding it to Arraylist in order to print out to the console.
But the last line (String flag=sc.nextLine();) is missing when running the program, as well as I can't add data to the list.
Any ideas guys?

HERE is my code, but I think my "input" method is wrong:

```java
import java.util.*;
class Course {
    public String courseId;
    public String courseName;
    public double courseDuration;
    public String courseStatus;
    public String courseflag;
    Course[] course = new Course[5];
    ArrayList<Course> myCourse = new ArrayList<Course>(10);
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    public Course(){
        this.courseId=null;
        this.courseName=null;
        this.courseDuration=0.0d;
        this.courseStatus=null;
        this.courseflag=null;
    }
    public Course(String id, String name, double duration, String status, String flag){
        this.courseId=id;
        this.courseName=name;
        this.courseDuration=duration;
        this.courseStatus=status;
        this.courseflag=flag;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return courseId + " " + courseName + " " + courseDuration+" " + courseStatus+" " + courseflag;
    }
    public void input(){
        for(int i=0; i<2;i++)
        {
            System.out.println ("\nData of Course"+ (i+1)+", please input by following order : ID, name, duration, status, flag");
            String id=sc.nextLine();
            String name=sc.nextLine();
            Double duration=sc.nextDouble();
            String status=sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println ("\n");
            String flag=sc.nextLine();
      
            myCourse.add(new Course(id,  name,  duration,  status,  flag)); 
        }
    }
}

public class assign501 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Course my = new Course();
        my.input( );
        System.out.println (my.myCourse);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the specific problem that you're having? As it is now, your question is exceedengly broad and vague and looks a lot like "please do this homework assignment for me". And that's not how Stack Overflow works. That said, why do you have an ArrayList at all? And why do you have an array of five Courses instead of ten?

Comment: "I think my "input" method is wrong" <- If you think that then therte must be a reason why. Does the method not compile? Does the method result in an Error/Exception when it is run? Do you output you don't expect?

Comment: Yes, guys, I have rewritten my question to be more clear.  I want to input 5 lines but only 4 works, furthermore, I can not add the data to the arraylist :(

Comment: Add `sc.nextLine();` after `Double duration = sc.nextDouble();` in method `input` of class `Course`.

Comment: @Abra tks bro, but it doesnt work unfortunately

Comment: Of-course it does. I tested it. Either the code you are running is not the same as in your question or you misunderstood which part to change (although I don't know how to make it more clear apart from posting the whole code but I can't do that in a comment).

Comment: I suspect that your issue is related to the mixed use of `nextLine()` with `nextDouble()`.  The latter does not consume the end-of-line that presumably follows it.  As such, the subsequent `nextLine()` will read the remainder of that line.  So the final `nextLine()` is reading the `flag` value instead of `status` and you never read `flag`.  Consider using `nextLine()` for all and parsing the `Double` from the `String`.

Answer (score 0):

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Course {
    public String courseId;
    public String courseName;
    public double courseDuration;
    public String courseStatus;
    public String courseflag;
    Course[] course = new Course[5];
    ArrayList<Course> myCourse = new ArrayList<Course>(10);
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public Course() {
        this.courseId = null;
        this.courseName = null;
        this.courseDuration = 0.0d;
        this.courseStatus = null;
        this.courseflag = null;
    }

    public Course(String id, String name, double duration, String status, String flag) {
        this.courseId = id;
        this.courseName = name;
        this.courseDuration = duration;
        this.courseStatus = status;
        this.courseflag = flag;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return courseId + " " + courseName + " " + courseDuration + " " + courseStatus + " "
                + courseflag;
    }

    public void input() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            System.out.println("\nData of Course" + (i + 1)
                    + ", please input by following order : ID, name, duration, status, flag");
            String id = sc.nextLine();
            String name = sc.nextLine();
            Double duration = sc.nextDouble();
//            sc.nextLine();
            String status = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("\n");
            String flag = sc.nextLine();

            myCourse.add(new Course(id, name, duration, status, flag));
        }

    }
}

public class assign501 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Course my = new Course();
        my.input();
        System.out.println(my.myCourse);
    }
}
```

Sample run:

```
Data of Course1, please input by following order : ID, name, duration, status, flag
ID_1
Name_1
1 Status_1


Flag_1

Data of Course2, please input by following order : ID, name, duration, status, flag
ID_2
Name_2
2 Status_2


Flag_2
[ID_1 Name_1 1.0  Status_1 Flag_1, ID_2 Name_2 2.0  Status_2 Flag_2]
```

From the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html) of class `java.util.Scanner`

> A `Scanner` breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace.

"Whitespace" includes space, tab and new-line.

I assume that you enter the value for `courseDuration` and then hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. Method [nextDouble](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble()) reads the number but not the new-line that is due to you pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. Hence the following call to `nextLine` reads that new-line as the value for `courseStatus`. Then you think that you are entering a value for `courseStatus` but you are actually entering a value for `courseflag`, since `courseStatus` has been already assigned a value of an empty string. Therefore you think that no value was entered for `courseflag`.

That's why, in the above "sample run" I enter both `courseDuration` and `courseStatus` on the same line and separate them by a single space.

Alternatively, you can uncomment the `sc.nextLine();` in the above code (as I wrote in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72528437/can-not-input-the-data-to-array-list-including-both-string-and-values#comment128122460_72528437)) which will allow you to enter `courseDuration` and `courseStatus` on different lines. Here is a sample run that demonstrates.

```
Data of Course1, please input by following order : ID, name, duration, status, flag
ID_1
Name_1
1
Status_1


Flag_1

Data of Course2, please input by following order : ID, name, duration, status, flag
ID_2
Name_2
2
Status_2


Flag_2
[ID_1 Name_1 1.0 Status_1 Flag_1, ID_2 Name_2 2.0 Status_2 Flag_2]
```

Here is a sample run using only the code in your question.

```
Data of Course1, please input by following order : ID, name, duration, status, flag
ID_1
Name_1
1


Status_1

Data of Course2, please input by following order : ID, name, duration, status, flag
ID_2
Name_2
2


Status_2
[ID_1 Name_1 1.0  Status_1, ID_2 Name_2 2.0  Status_2]
```

Notice, in the last line, that there are two spaces between `1.0` and `Status_1`? That's because `Status_1` is actually the value of `courseflag` and the actual value of `courseStatus` is an empty string. Similarly, there are two spaces between `2.0` and `Status_2`.